# Hello World Google App Engine not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/intro/gettingstarted) simple tutorial to create a hello world app, but on testing ("Starting the development server") it fails to run. When I click on "logs" in the launcher, I have

```
in "C:\...\app.yaml", line 1, column 14
2013-07-13 19:48:38 (Process exited with code 1)
```

The 14th line in the .yaml file is `version: "2.5.2"`. Can it cause the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a more complete log, without a proper stack trace we don't know what kind of error, just that there is an error.

Comment: That is the entire log :/

Comment: please try `version: "2.5.1"` which is what the tutorial has. if that works it could be your SDK version. what is your SDK version?

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. Launcher's about says `release 1.8.1`. (I've tried to change it to that, but it didn't work too).

Comment: Its **column 14** not line. Can you show us at least first two-three lines of your code?

Comment: @Thanks Dunno - that was the first letter of my app name, and I guess it couldn't be upper case!

Comment: btw, my error log is 40 lines long, you should investigate how to get proper/full logs on your system. this will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Google App Engine SDK download page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) pointed me to a different ["Getting started"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) page which in turn leads me to a different [`helloworld` tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld). In that different tutorial they do not have the `libraries` section in the `app.yaml` file.

For the sake of the tutorial, please use the link above and remove the offending section. I will give an update as I will try the tutorial you pointed to.

---

From a blank project after creating the `app.yaml` I get:

```
Value 'your_app_id' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
  in "../apps/app.yaml", line 1, column 14
```

I replaced `application: your_app_id` with `application: your-app-id`.

Comment: Changed my app name to all lower case and it worked. I've accepted your answer as the only answer. Thanks!

Comment: the tutorial I was looking at has the correct ​`application: your-app-id`, it may be more up-to-date w.r.t small mistakes.

Comment: I am now not able to publish my app: `Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'idanruftest2').
--- end server output ---
2013-07-13 21:02:57 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you may need to follow this link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how clearly this is stated in the other answers but the name of your application can't being either capitalized or have underscores in the name. When naming your app use "example" instead of "Example", or "test-example", instead of "test_example".

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced issues regarding the same while running my Hello_world app

- the solution was finally in app.yaml file (as is the case most of the time)

  error:`application: hello_world`

  solution: `application: hello-world` (underscore sign replaced)